# Artisan command for clearing all session data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-artisan

What is the artisan command for clearing all session data in Laravel, I'm looking for something like:

```
$ php artisan session:clear
```

But apparently, it does not exist. How would I clear it from the command line?

I tried using

```
$ php artisan tinker  
...
\Session::flush();
```

But it flushes the session of only one user, I want to flush all sessions for all users. How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
artisan cache:clear
```

But it does not clear the session, again.

Comment: You can delete manually from storage/framework/sessions.You can write artisan command yourself to automate this process. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#writing-commands

Comment: I have it in table on staging and in flie on local and using one command would be easier and more universal.

Comment: And I'm lazy to run a Mysql Workbench just to truncate a table. It takes too long to load and too many steps to do.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

---

UPDATE: This question seems to be asked quite often and many people are still actively commenting on it.

In practice, it is a horrible idea to flush sessions using the

```
php artisan key:generate
```

It may wreak all kinds of havoc. The best way to do it is to clear whichever system you are using.

---

The Lazy Programmers guide to flushing all sessions:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Will make all sessions invalid because a new application key is specified

The not so Lazy approach

```
php artisan make:command FlushSessions
```

and then insert

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class flushSessions extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'session:flush';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Flush all user sessions';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('sessions')->truncate();
    }
}
```

and then

```
php artisan session:flush
```

Comment: Oh, some one else approved it. Great.

Comment: Have fun logging your users out :D

Comment: Do note that generating a new app key will break any other data that you might have encrypted in Laravel.

Comment: I wish I have a comprehensive list of this encrypted data, because  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980861/laravels-application-key-what-it-is-and-how-it-works#comment88473317_38980861) question is lacking a good answer.

Comment: Do NOT invalidate the apps key in a production app just because you want to get rid of sessions. It will also make all encrypted (not hashed) unreadable. Maybe your app doesn't store any encrypted data, but recommending it to strangers on StackOverflow doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Also, the second part of the answer only works when you store your sessions to a database. Note that this might often not be the case (for ex. if you use the Redis session store or use the cookie session store).

Comment: @miho Laravel's APP Key is only used to decrypt session cookies, therefore deleting them is a safe practice

Comment: @DevinGray Sadly, no. Check out the encryption documentation of Laravel, where it clearly says that the app key is used for all kind of encryptions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption

Comment: Significance of app key, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445420/what-is-the-significance-of-application-key-in-a-laravel-application

Comment: It only works if your SESSION_DRIVER is database. It wouldn't work in all other cases: file, cookie, redis, etc.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to regenerate the `APP_KEY` with `php artisan key:generate` because it will destroy all users passwords, isn't it?

Comment: What about the Redis driver. How access the session Redis connection ?

Comment: @algorhythm - No it does not destroy user passwords, I tested and it didn't. But I think it should.

Answer (score 52):

If you are using **file based sessions**, you can use the following linux command to clean the sessions folder out:

```
rm -f storage/framework/sessions/*
```

Comment: Please, provide explanation, I mean it is all right for it not to be an `artisan command` but it will only work if you use a `file driver` for your `session data`, right?

Comment: This also delete the `.gitignore` file who's there to preserve the (empty) folder when committing.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev the answer has been updated based on your feedback

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier it doesn't delete .gitignore

Answer (score 15):

If you want completely remove session for any driver.
Use this piece of code

```
\Session::getHandler()->gc(0); // Destroy all sessions which exist more than 0 minutes
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that PHP's `SessionHandlerInterface` does not force session drivers to provide any kind of `destroyAll()` method. Thus, it has to be implemented manually for each driver.

Taking ideas from different answers, I came up with this solution:

1. Create command

```sh
php artisan make:command FlushSessions
```

2. Create class in `app/Console/Commands/FlushSessions.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class FlushSessions extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'session:flush';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Flush all user sessions';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $driver = config('session.driver');
        $method_name = 'clean' . ucfirst($driver);
        if ( method_exists($this, $method_name) ) {
            try {
                $this->$method_name();
                $this->info('Session data cleaned.');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->error($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            $this->error("Sorry, I don't know how to clean the sessions of the driver '{$driver}'.");
        }
    }

    protected function cleanFile () {
        $directory = config('session.files');
        $ignoreFiles = ['.gitignore', '.', '..'];

        $files = scandir($directory);

        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            if( !in_array($file,$ignoreFiles) ) {
                unlink($directory . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function cleanDatabase () {
        $table = config('session.table');
        DB::table($table)->truncate();
    }
}
```

3. Run command

```sh
php artisan session:flush
```

Implementations for other drivers are welcome!

Comment: Missing "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;". Laravel 9.x and later doesn't need constructor. Other than that, a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to get rid of all sessions is to change the name of the session cookie. This can be easily done by changing the `'cookie' => '...'` line in `config/session.php` file.

This works independently of the session storage you use and also won't touch any other data except the session data (and thus seems preferable over the renewing the app key solution to me, where you would loose any encrypted data stored in the app).

Comment: Nice solution, thx. And you are right. The `APP_KEY` is also a salt for hashes created with `Hash::make()`. So users password and any other hashed data will be invalid after changing it.

Comment: Why is it better than changing `domain` in the same file?

Comment: @algorhythm bcrypt passwords will keep working. Unsure about other password hashing algorythms. You are correct about manually hashed database columns though that use the Laravel encryption functionality (because those need to be decrypted, unlike passwords).

Answer (score 1):

This thread is quite much old. But I would like to share my implementation of removing all sesssions for file based driver.

```
        $directory = 'storage/framework/sessions';
        $ignoreFiles = ['.gitignore', '.', '..'];
        $files = scandir($directory);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if(!in_array($file,$ignoreFiles)) unlink($directory . '/' . $file);
        }
```

Why I have not used linux command 'rm'?

Because PHP is one of the prerequisites for Laravel and Linux is not. Using this Linux command will make our project implementable on Linux environment only.
That's why it is good to use PHP in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

My solution
Laravel

```html
// SESSION_DRIVER=file


$files = File::allFiles(storage_path('framework/sessions/'));
foreach($files as $file){
  File::delete(storage_path('framework/sessions/'.$file->getFilename()));
}
//OR

//SESSION_DRIVER=redis

Artisan::call('cache:clear'); // == php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but what worked for me is just remove the cookies.

In Chrome, go to your develop console, go to the tab "Application". Find "Cookies" in the sidebar and click on the little arrow in front of it. Go to your domainname and click on the icon next to the filter field to clear the cookies for your domain. Refresh page, and all session data is new and the old ones are removed.

Comment: This is great for a developer, but what about users?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no built-in artisan command for clearing file based session data.

For this you can **manually remove the session files** of `storage/framework/sessions` folder.

Or you can **create your own artisan command** to do that:

1. Create your command file:

```
php artisan make:command ClearSessions
```

2. Edit the file `app\Console\Commands\ClearSessions.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class ClearSessions extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'session:clear';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Remove session files in storage/framework/sessions/';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Get all files in session directory
        $files = File::glob(storage_path('framework/sessions/*'));

        // Exclude the .ignore file
        $files = array_filter($files, function ($file) {
            return basename($file) !== '.ignore';
        });

        File::delete(...$files);

        $this->info('Session cleared successfully.');
    }
}
```

3. Run your command:

```
php artisan session:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use database session , just delete all data on that table.
In my case it is 'sessions' table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the database for session driver, then empty the sessions table. Regenerating the key will cause a lot of problems if you are using single login on many subdomains. Emptying the session table helps reduce the useless data in the session table. You can delete cookies on everyone's browswer.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, then truncate the session table. Go to Artisan Tinker, then truncate the table.

```
php artisan tinker

DB::table('sessions')->truncate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a command and put this line of code `Session::flush();` into the handle function. Then register your command as like  `protected $signature = 'session:flush';`
Finally, run the command `php artisan session:flush`.
Hope that it will work.