# #PHP, Laravel Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, shopify

I've been stuck with this for a few days. I know that it's probably the most asked question about shopify Oauth.

To begin with, I got an shopify app to work with, the client asked me to make some modifications and I am facing issues with local environment setup.

I am using Ngrok for tunneling my connections.

Here is the redirect_uri parameter:

```
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ff7311e59.ngrok.io%2Fauth
```

and full request url:

```
https://{shop.domain}.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=eb5bba2f0a8474bad5fd687e055056af&scope=read_products,write_products,read_themes,write_themes&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ff7311e59.ngrok.io%2Fauth
```

and here are all whitelisted redirection URL's in app settings

```
https://f7311e59.ngrok.io/auth
https://f7311e59.ngrok.io/auth/
http://f7311e59.ngrok.io/auth
http://f7311e59.ngrok.io/auth/
```

Hopefully I'm not blind, because i don't see any mismatches in those urls

```
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ff7311e59.ngrok.io%2Fauth

https://f7311e59.ngrok.io/auth
```

I am wondering if this could be some specific aplication architecture issue, also I am new at shopify app's developement so maybe there's something I've missed. Thanks

Comment: Probably obvious but have you double checked that the client ID eb5bba2f0a8474bad5fd687e055056af is the same app with those whitelisted redirection URLs?

Comment: @JoshBrown Yup, they are the same. After digging for a few more hours, I tried to regenerate laravel app key, and re-cache config with `artisan config:cache`, and it works, app installs, but still haven't found the cause of the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980861/laravels-application-key-what-it-is-and-how-it-works?answertab=votes#tab-top

this comment maybe helpful.

Comment: try this type https://fa52f20b.ngrok.io/shopify/auth/callback  in your whitelisted.. Actually it depends on your endpoint routing .. but if you  are using package , some  package  has default endpoint setting like i have mentioned . And please do not use url  4 time , 2 tie is enough , one is https  and another is http

Comment: check your app url and Allowed redirection URL(s) with http to https if you use ngrock.