# Invalid Request (UNEXPECTED EOF) PHP

Tags: php

so it's been 2 hours since I started working on this problem. I only get `Invalid Request (UNEXPECTED EOF)` in my CLI and not be able to debug. This is the class I created:

```
$newUserLastID = NULL;
    function addNewUser($request, $team) {
        global $newUserLastID;

        $db = new db();
        $db->setErrorCallbackFunction("myErrorHandler", "text");
        $status = "1";
        $activated = "1";
        $randString = generateRandomString();
        $hashed = password_hash($randString, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


        $db->insert("accounts", array(
                    "team" => $team,
                    "username" => $request,
                    "nickname" => $request,
                    "password" => $hashed,
                    "status" => $status,
                    //"recruiter" => $recruiterID,
                    "activation" => $activated,
                    "textpword" => $randString

                ));
        $newUserLastID = $db->lastInsertId(); 
         return $newUserLastID;

    }
```

And when I want to get the `$newUserLastID` value,

```
$somevar = addNewUser('DummyData', 'DummyData2');
```

The code is being executed but, I always get `Invalid Request (UNEXPECTED EOF)` in my CLI and it stops. What do you think is wrong with my code?

Comment: UNEXPECTED EOF means you have a syntax error on your page may be you miss some { or } or ; or (,) any thing that gives the error of EOF (End of File)

Comment: in `CLI` run `php -l filename` to verify syntax

Comment: @AlexAndrei No syntax errors detected

Comment: on all files involved?

Comment: Yes, btw I am using a framework @AlexAndrei

Comment: your function return nothing, so there will be no value in $somevar, add "return varname"  at the end of your function

Comment: apologies, I confused the error message check these questions and subsequent answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141240/php-local-server-invalid-request-unexpected-eof and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480398/php-built-in-webserver-throws-invalid-request-unexpected-eof-after-every-files

Comment: next time please do say what you are using and how, less is not more when talking about context and details

Comment: I am using firefox sir @AlexAndrei

Comment: does the same thing happen if you run it on apache or nginx? try that

Comment: Yes sir @AlexAndrei. I hope this wouldn't happen in production

Comment: try disabling all browser extension and check

Comment: @user3782114 nothing worked

Comment: last thing you can do is check values stores in variables like $request,$hashed,  make sure it do not contains "(,),{,}"